# Make group of images behave as a block (ex:resize together)!

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to make a couple of images resize together (as a block) when the window is resized by the user (or simply to adapt to different screen sizes).

All images are in a table, row1/column1= map plus river images. row1/column2= description of the rivers which can be viewed by clicking on each river on the map.

1)Main Image is a map and its on Z-Index:-1 Position:absolute;
2)Following images are rivers positioned absolutely on top of the map. These images have a mouseover behavior to swap image with it self but another color, plus onclick that makes text on the table cell on the next column to move to specific anchor.

Like this theres interactivity with the user and map/rivers.

The thing is when the screen is smaller the map image resizes accordingly but the river images stay put and all gets messed up.

Below a bit of the html code refering the map image and one river image (all other simply repeat)

"HTML"

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="page-bg">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1"   id="interactive">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="100%">
<img src="../images/backgrounds/01_FFAlgarve_Background.png" width="100%"  height="1050" alt="" id="intmap">
<a href="#a3" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('funcho','','../images/buttons/funcho1.png',1)">
<img src="../images/buttons/funcho.png" alt="" width="100%" height="auto" id="funcho" title="Funcho Dam">
```

"CSS"

//table

```
#interactive{
 position:relative;
 z-index:-1;
}
```

//map image

```
#intmap{
 position:absolute; 
 z-index:-1;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 max-width:1750px;
 }
```

//river image

```
#funcho{
 position:absolute; 
 z-index:2;
 top:510px;
 left:650px;
 max-width:222px;
 max-height:132px;
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance for all the help I may get ;)
Kind Regards
MSV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're using a fixed value for your rivers,  `left:650px;` is still 650px from the left, even if the map is only 300px wide.

Try using percentages instead.

//edit
So your map is 1050px high, originally your river is 510 from the top, so `100(510/1050) = 48.57`

```
#river {
top:48.57%;
}
```

Comment: Hi Tieskevo thanks for your reply. That resolves the problem of the rivers staying on it previous position, they don't resize accordingly though. Well they don't resize at all.

Comment: Calculate the width of the rivers aswell :)

Comment: Thanks Tieskevo the percentages tip really helped, it brings other problems though. Just did it on jsfiddle to see if theres a better overall view of it ;)

Comment: Finnally solved it, thanks for all the help. Based it on percentages and it works ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try using media queries
resize window to see where your layout breaks and use media queries to modify css for the desired window size

in your css file put this

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 370px)
{
    //Desired css goes here
}
```

The css put in the above example will work for a window size >= 370 px

You can have as many queries as you want with different max or min widths
Only put the rules that you are changing for the id or the class.Any other rules will stay the same as defined outside media query

And yes percentages will help you a lot but can cause extra problems experiment with media queries and percentagies

Comment: Hi Kinggeov thanks for your reply. I tried it and the page breaks on max-width:2500px, above that it shows the layour properly, under that it breaks and all the objects simply follow the Dom structure or the positioning attributes.

Comment: So try changing css for max widths you dont like your layout you can have as many as you want. It is the best way to have a responsive layout. Try to post some code in jsfiddle to see what you are trying to accomplish and im sure i can help you further

Comment: Hi Kinggeov, once again thanks for the help. here ya go for jsfiddle (despite no images showing up, only text content.... https://jsfiddle.net/marcosv/jw2z7xz4/

Comment: Well the resizing issue is now resolved. But since the screen is rectangular the resizing of the rivers according to the map happens only if the window is resized in width and height proportionally to the original window. I mean if its simply reduced in width then the rivers will resize but won't be in the right position above the map...

Comment: try to use vwidths or vhights search google for this. Supports only modern browsers, but i insist you can solve this with media qweries

Comment: googleing info on this subject. thanks for the support.

Comment: So with media queries its basically make as many different display styles as needed? like for desktops, tables and smartphones (basics). so instead of making it automatically work for any possible resolution I do something that fits those. If I have a resolution in between though the displayed layouts are gonna suck cause all will be dispersed and out of place, correct or am I confusing it all?

Comment: Yes you are correct.but you can check v-widths and v-hights also for your problem

Comment: well tbh on the first google search I did didn't find anything about v-widths and v-heights. gonna continue searching though. Thanks

Comment: Thanks King, it works now based on % but you media queries tip is very good for the future. Cheers

Comment: Sorry once again, It was working properly and all of a sudden it doesn't work anymore. I didn't make any changes to it simply inserted a function on another page and after that all went crazy.....Erased the function (since it was the only change i made) and it didn't work still....HOW is this possible??? Getting crazy... May it be JQuery libraries related?Updates? Thanks for the help.